# Getting an inventory in another if statement

Tags: java, bukkit

So basically what I am trying to do is make it so every player has their own extra storage bag that they can upgrade(starting on that later), but at the moment I am stuck with this. I am making it so if the Hashmap "storage" does not contain a value, to create a new inventory and set it a value. The only problem is I cannot then use the inventory "bag" in another if statement to open it when the value is set. Here is my code :

```
package me.impatheimpaler.aqw;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler; 
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;

public class Storage implements Listener{

public me.impatheimpaler.aqw.Main plugin;

public HashMap<String, Inventory> storage = new HashMap<String, Inventory>();

public Storage(Main main) {
    plugin = main;
}

@EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {

    if (!(e.getItem().getType() == Material.CHEST)) return;
    if (!(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) return;

    if (e.getItem().getItemMeta().hasLore() && 
            e.getItem().getItemMeta().getLore().contains(ChatColor.GREEN + "A bag for extra storage.")) {

        if (storage.containsKey(null) && storage.containsValue(null)) {
            Inventory bag = Bukkit.getServer().createInventory(e.getPlayer(), 9, "Storage");
            storage.put(e.getPlayer().getName(), bag);
        }

        if (storage.contains(e.getPlayer().getName(), bag)) {
            //Here is the error, as I cannot use the value "bag", because it cannot be 
            accessed from another if statement.

        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just declare `bag` outside of the if statement, then set it inside of the statement:

```
Inventory bag;
if(storage.containsKey(null) && storage.containsValue(null)){
  //code
}
```

So, it could look something like this:

```
Inventory bag;
if (storage.containsKey(null) && storage.containsValue(null)) {
    bag = Bukkit.getServer().createInventory(e.getPlayer(), 9, "Storage");
    storage.put(e.getPlayer().getName(), bag);
}

if (storage.contains(e.getPlayer().getName(), bag)) {
    //use "bag" however you want
}
```

Also, instead of checking if `storage.containsKey(null)`, to check if the player's name *NOT* is in the `HashMap`, you should use:

```
if(!storage.containsKey(e.getPlayer().getName()){
```

Doing `storage.containsKey(null)` will check if the map has `null` as a key, it won't find anything out about the player